# Transforming content in css pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-transforms

I am trying to add a triangle to a div to create some sort of speech bubble. That bubble is supposed to have a shadow. I found that you can use unicode and mix it into a pseudo element to create a triangle. Now I am a bit puzzled how I could scale the Unicode Character as it looks a bit odd.

```
...:after {
content: "◀";
transform: scaleY(2.5); //doesnt seem to work :-(
top: 50px;
left: -11px;
position: absolute;
text-shadow: -1px 0 2px #ccc;
pointer-events: none; }
```

Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform :before or :after item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108346/transform-before-or-after-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** You can use `font-size` for pseudo elements to make the text larger.  Just add `font-size:2.5em;`.

**NEW IDEA:** I know the question was about transforming the content arrow, but for an alternate solution for your speech bubble.  What about using the css border arrow "hack" (See my codepen link below w/ extended example):

```
.bubble:after {
  content:"";
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #cccccc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:-20px;
  /* Now transform will work since this is not a character: */
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.5);
  transform: scaleY(1.5);
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/djfarrelly/pen/BKLwe)

Comment: font-size does change the size but enlarges the element proportionally (i.e. scales on x and y in the same way). I was hoping just to transform the element in one direction.

Comment: @zaph0t Try my alternate solution using a css border arrow "hack" instead of the arrow character.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using:

```
transform: scaleY(...)
```

Have you tried using:

```
zoom:2.5;
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/79fDM/)

Comment: note: this is not supported by FireFox (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom)