# Transform :before or :after item

Tags: css

Is there a way to apply transform onto an element inserted with :before?

The following does not work, but I'm open to other solutions.

```
.itemclass:before  {
  content: "➨";
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is that arrow font is - can i get that in notepad

Comment: I pulled the arrow from here: http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Transforms can't be applied to non-replaced `inline` elements. Add:

```
display:inline-block;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/epomil/1/edit)

Side-note: Though this doesn't apply to this use case, `absolute`/`fixed` positioning would discard the need for a `display` property as these are automatically treated as `display:block`.

Also, check the definition of [transformable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element):

> A transformable element is an element in the HTML namespace which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose ‘`display`’ property computes to ‘`table-row`’, ‘`table-row-group`’, ‘`table-header-group`’, ‘`table-footer-group`’, ‘`table-cell`’, or ‘`table-caption`’; or an element in the SVG namespace (see [[SVG11]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#SVG11)) which has the attributes ‘[`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#effects)’, ‘`patternTransform`’ or ‘`gradientTransform`’.

Comment: Thanks! The first time I read this I misunderstood it, but this works great.